# Is Blaster worm still dangerous on Windows 10?

Tags: worm

I was able to successfully compile the [blaster worm source code](https://gist.github.com/yorickdewid/a9fb98da3c367b360e36). I have its executable file now but I'm not sure if it is safe to run this file on my Windows 10 computer or not. What might happen if I do?

Comment: Why do you want to run it? It wouldn't be able to spread itself at least, since the bug the worm exploited is long gone. Most likely it's not even _compatible_ with modern versions of Windows...

Comment: @forest For educational purposes

Comment: Then I'd run it in a virtual machine with a vulnerable version of Windows installed and networking disabled. Skimming through the source code... it's not going to be able to do any damage unless your network is up, in which case it might try a SYN flood attack.

Comment: @forest Any recommendations for Windows XP virtual machines?

Comment: VirtualBox is a good VM which is easy to use and supports Windows XP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not an issue anymore. Even a patched Windows 2000 or Windows XP would not be attacked by it.

MS-Blaster exploited a [buffer overflow on DCOM-RPC](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/security-updates/securitybulletins/2003/ms03-026), and the fix was provided a month before MS-Blaster hit. So even when it was active, computers that were fully patched were not affected.

If you run it now, it would send a crafted message to your system (and every system reachable by it) but unless you have an ancient and not patched Windows running, nobody will get affected.

It could send data to internet computers too, but I doubt it would find any vulnerable Windows 2000 or XP active and online either.